# How to select only Filled records from database?

Tags: php

To Show only filled records from table.

Here is my database:

```
CREATE TABLE `category1` (
  `parent_id` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `parent_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `cat_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `cat_status` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Dumping data into db:

```
INSERT INTO `category1` (`parent_id`, `parent_name`, `cat_name`, `cat_status`) VALUES
(1, 'Electronics', '', 'Active'),
(2, '', 'Laptops', 'Active'),
(3, '', 'Mobiles', 'Active'),
(4, 'Mens', '', 'Active'),
(5, '', 'Watches', 'Active');
```

Now here I want parent_name field to be display but the thing is If I do
"select parent_name from table" It also shows me the empty records of the field. Reason why those are empty because at a time only parent_name or cat_name can be filled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to add a where condition to your query:

```
select parent_name from category1 where parent_name != ''
```

You may be interested in distinct parent_name values. In that case, use the distinct statement in your query:

```
select distinct parent_name from category1 where parent_name != ''
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT parent_name FROM category1 WHERE parent_name != ''
```

will select all rows where parent_name is not blank.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `query`

```
SELECT parent_name FROM category1 WHERE (parent_name != '' AND parent_name IS NOT NULL)
```

The `IS NOT NULL` condition is used in `SQL` to test for a `non-NULL value`. It returns `TRUE` if a non-NULL value is found, otherwise it returns `FALSE`.

Answer (score 0):

this will guarantee no empty values

```
 SELECT parent_name FROM table WHERE parent_name != ''
```